# Get number of rows on specific datatables page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to get the count of the number of rows on the current dataTables page. If I do this:

```
alert($('.tableViewer tbody tr').length)
```

It gives me the a non-accurate row count (I think it adds the current page and the last one?).

Anyway, I'm just trying to get the row count on the page I'm actually on. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's my delete button:

```
function fnDelete(elem){
    if (selected.length>0) {
        var c;
        c = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the selected ${displayTableName}?');
        if (c) {
            // Create delete url from editor url...
            var deleteURL = (urlstr.substring(0, urlstr.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)) + "delete.do";
            alert($('.tableViewer tbody tr').length)
            deleteRecord(deleteURL,selected[0]);

            alert($('.tableViewer tbody tr').length)
            if ( $('.tableViewer tbody tr').length === 1) {
                setTimeout(function() { oTable.fnPageChange('last'); }, 100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are hidden rows? `$('.tableViewer tbody tr:visible').length`

Comment: you are doing the right way actually. inspect your dom elements

Comment: @JoeFletch -- that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! If you write it in an answer I'll be sure to pick it as the correct one and upvote you as well. This was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tr` elements may be on the page, but not visible. Try this!

```
$('.tableViewer tbody tr:visible').length
```

Comment: Keep in mind that even if there are no records to show in the table, there would still be one visible row that says 'No matching records found'. The following returns false if no records exist: $('.tableViewer tbody tr:first td').hasClass( 'dataTables_empty' )